# Removing lines between containers (flutter/dart)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Click for a sample image:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rctNx.png)

How can I remove these lines?
I have already used BoxDecoration()

e.g.

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            height: 70,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0.5),
              child: Text(
                'Anmeldung',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto Bold',
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

It's all in a Scaffold().

The container is in a column widget placed.

Is there any possibility?

Comment: Can you drop your whole Page code? The code above doesn't seem enough to understand why the lines show

Comment: Where is that container placed ? Is that a listview or column widget ? Please add more details

Comment: The container is in a column widget placed.

Comment: Can you add the column to the code?

Comment: I created this dartpad to try and figure out what is going on.  The code that you posted doesn't show lines, therefore it's coming from another source, not the container itself. I believe you need to post more of your code.  http://dartpad.dev/94b3b31ae4f1f384669258dfda460f69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is. I believe that you have a mismatch of colors with background and foreground because you're setting the color to white in the container. I created this dartpad to show you what I mean:

https://dartpad.dev/94b3b31ae4f1f384669258dfda460f69

Only one of the containers have a Decorator... and it looks like has lines. The container itself does not create any lines.

Try removing the decoration since it will match the background color.

(also, from your picture, it appears that the widget that contains your button is the problem... not the part that says "Anmeldung")

Answer (score 5):

Change this part of code

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
        width: 0, color: Colors.white),
    color: Colors.white,
),
```